# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in wordpress custom script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My jquery file is not working in WordPress.
The error is here:

[image]

My js code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#read_more').click(function() {
    $('.display_none').show().animate({'transition': '2s'});
   });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

I have an added `custom-script.js` file in `functions.php` like this:

```
function aristo_css_js(){
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom-script.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','aristo_css_js');
```

What is the main problem for this was not working? But if I added custom script code before `body` tag it's working. ?

Comment: Make sure you're loading jQuery into the page.

Comment: Check the order of your scripts, chances are your own is loaded before jQuery.

Comment: Thanks I got the problem and it solved.@JackBashford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my own question by add `jquery` file before my `custom-script`

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-main', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom-script.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue once.

WordPress ships with its own version of the jQuery library.

Try using `jQuery` instead of just `$` sign.

For example:

```
var svg = $("#svg-container");
```

should be replaced with

```
var svg = jQuery("#svg-container");
```

Comment: 1. OP is already doing this (IIFE passing jQuery) 2. check the error message OP has posted: `jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Then double check the order  of your scripts. Make sure the jquery script is before your custom script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this updated javascript code,

```html
jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#read_more').click(function() {
    jQuery('.display_none').show().animate({'transition': '2s'});
   });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
function aristo_css_js(){
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-main', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom-script.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','aristo_css_js');
```

Thanks!

Comment: I already mentioned it on my question. I found the same error when I change with code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will fix your issue

```
(function($) {

// Use $() inside of this function like so 

$(#selector)

})(jQuery);
```